# Possible Biolinum bug with italic bold face

Tags: fonts, libertine

The following example produces some wrong font shapes:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[biolinum]{libertine}

\begin{document}
\textsf{\textit{\textbf{E L g h}}}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get:
[image: BiolinumProblem] 
(I am using OsX 10.10.1, MacTeX 2014, I update my installation through TeX Live, and I have libertine version 5.3.0)
Is this my mistake, a problem with my installation, or a bug of the font?

Thanks!

Comment: For me this produces a slanted sans serif bold font - as described in the documentation.  Can you post an image or describe what you get?

Comment: I can confirm; with `pdflatex` I get the same shapes. With LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX the glyphs are OK.

Comment: I get the same as Nicola and egreg with pdfLaTeX. @AndrewSwann Is it clean for you with pdfLaTeX? If so, what version do you have? My `libertine.sty` is from 2014-11-25.

Comment: @cfr I see the same problem with pdflatex, at least on screen with large magnification.  I haven't tried printing.

Comment: @egreg Is this a bug in the font or a bug in the support package? I tried to figure this out but didn't get very far yet.

Comment: @cfr The Type1 font has been converted from OpenType wrongly.

Comment: You should probably send an e-mail to Bob Tennent (rdt at cs.queensu.ca) about this. He's the one who maintains the ``libertine`` package.

Comment: The fonts have been fixed!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug in the Type1 version of the Biolinum font; the Type1 font used by the combination slanted/boldface is `LinBiolinumTBO.pfb` and this is what `fontforge` shows for the character “L”

[image]

where the corner is quite evident.

The same character in the OpenType font

[image]

## Important update

Bob Tennent has submitted an [updated version of the fonts on CTAN](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg06706.html). After updating my TeX Live, the output of the test file in the question is

[image]

Comment: I see today the announcement at http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg06706.html about which I'll report as soon as possible.